# How to get access to Google Tag Manager that was handled by a previous developer?

Tags: seo, google-tag-manager

My client site has GTM script included within the `<head>...</head>` but the client doesn't seem to have access to their GTM account, which is most likely handled by a previous developer.

Is there a way to get access to GTM account from my client's end (as it'll have their domain linked to it) or does my client need to chase it up with the previous developer and have the account permissions transferred?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Google My Business and several other Google services that allow customers to prove ownership and regain control using their domain email address such `info@example.com`, GTM does not.

*Unless you have [Google Tag Manager 360](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6357156?hl=en&ref_topic=6377428) then you would need to know:*

1. *The Google account used to create the GTM container (email address)*
2. *The password or the ability to reset the password.*

FREE GTM accounts have no SLA or Support, but if you had a 360 account then Customer Support would be willing to help you and manually delegate a new admin. Paid customers get support and more features.

Easily method would be to start a new container but this time using a Google account operating on the actual domain, e.g `info@example.com`, that way you always have a method of resetting it.